# How to get rid of broken Python Environments in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, anaconda

I have to do a new course for University using python. A year or so ago I have installed Anaconda, but never really worked with it. Before starting I wanted to update everything, so I uninstalled my python and Anaconda version and reinstalled the newest version (I know I could have just updated everything).

I would like to work with VS2017, since this is the IDE I'm used to work with (coming from a c# background), however within the python environment window, my old versions are still visible, although with a strike-through font:

[image]

VS2017 has no option to remove the broken/uninstalled environments, but refers you to [this website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/managing-python-environments-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2017#fix-invalid-environments). In the bottom section there is a description to my solve my problem. Normally I don't really like to edit the registry, since I'm not know my way around this stuff, however this being directly from the learn.microsoft.com pages, I thought it was ok.

Problem only is, the changes didn't have any effect on my issue whatsoever. 
(already did the obvious stuff like restarting VS2017 and Windows).

**Additional Info**
My problem is that I wanted to run the python script skeleton we got from the course to check if all the modules and python itself is working properly. However I always get a `dll load failed` error on some of the modules (`matplotlib` for example). Running the scripts on other IDEs (like Anaconda's integrated Spyder IDE) however works just fine, so I know the modules are good to go on my machine. I wanted to rule the above mentioned issue out as source of error before looking further.

Comment: _"the changes"_ -- what exact changes? What did you see in Registry of what the docs mention and what did you change? _"didn't have any effect on my issue whatsoever"_ -- clarify. Do you still see exactly the same in the Python Environments as you showed?

Comment: Also, did you try any of other measures that the docs mention, like repairing the installed Python products?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev yes everything looked like the description and I deleted the python 3.6 node. I didn't repair version 3.6 since I had it uninstalled.

Comment: Do you really not have the other Python products installed? You may have installed them per-user, in which case you'll need to run `appwiz.cpl` as yourself, without elevation.

Comment: Hmm, if I remenber correctly the old version 3.6 was installed only on my user and the new one is for all users. I will look into that.

Comment: For cases like this, `procmon` can be useful to see what VS is finding in the registry and on the disk. Uninstalling all Python products and searching the registry and disk for "python" and "conda" should also find any remnants.

Comment: ok, I will try that and report back here - Thanks for your help so far!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking with [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) (starting up VS with monitoring active, up to bringing up the Python environments list in it; then stopping monitoring and setting filters: `Process name` is `devenv.exe`, `Path` contains `python`, `conda` or `ContinuumAnalytics` (three separate filters)) shows that VS searches these locations for Python installation data:

- Registry keys, under **HKCU** (the document fails to mention this) and **HKLM**:

  - `\Software\Python` and `\Software\Wow6432Node\Python` ([which is seen as the former by 32-bit processes](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/registry-wow6432-node.html))
- Files:

  - `<user profile>\.conda` directory
  - It also looks for `conda.exe` in a few locations

    - I don't have it, but if I did, it would be possible to see with `procmon` which command lines VS is invoking it with. Then you could e.g. do the same yourself and see what information VS gets from it.

If VS finds the entries that you list, something referring to what you see in the list *must* be under these locations somewhere.

---

To remove the entries, as I already mentioned,

- First check if you have the corresponding product installed and uninstall it if you do. Entries under `HKCU` refer to products installed per-user so you'll have to run `appwiz.cpl` as yourself <sub>(or rather, as the same user that you run VS as)</sub> to see them.
- If you really don't have it installed, do the usual manual cleansing procedure. Delete anything from the registry and disk that looks relevant (by name, location), including the above entries. At your own risk, of course. For VS to stop finding them, deleting the entries should be enough. You can also try to reinstall and uninstall the exact same version of software (which can be tricky to find) and hope it uninstalls correctly this time.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the issue was with the Phyton node being in HKCU. I uninstalled all Python related stuff and then deleted the Python 3.6 node there. Now my Python Environment window is cleaned up, I will make a fresh install of Anaconda and hopefully everything will be fine after that!

Answer (score 1):

To correct python environment in Visual Studio that doesn't have a repair option, or to remove an invalid environment, use the following steps to modify the registry directly. Visual Studio automatically updates the Python Environments window when you make changes to the registry.

1. Run regedit.exe.
2. Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python. For IronPython, look
   for IronPython instead.
3. Expand the node that matches the distribution, such as Python Core
   for CPython or ContinuumAnalytics for Anaconda. For IronPython,
   expand the version number node.
4. Inspect the values under the InstallPath node:
   [image]
5. If the environment still exists on your computer, change the value of ExecutablePath to the correct location. Also correct the (Default) and WindowedExecutablePath values as necessary.
6. If the environment no longer exists on your computer and you want to remove it from the Python Environments window, delete the parent node of InstallPath, such as 3.6 in the image above.

Ref: Microsoft Doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/managing-python-environments-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#fix-or-delete-invalid-environments